# Labelling polygons intersecting another polygon file

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, intersection, contour, identity

I have a series of polygons representing land packages and another shapefile representing contour polygons of flood elevations in steps i.e 2-5m 5-10m >10m. I am wanting to label a polygon with the highest it intersects with i.e if there if there is a threshold change across the one asset it is labelled with the highest.

I have tried using an identity but that splits my land packages up into two if there is a threshold change going across it. I want to keep the same number of packages with whatever check I do it with.

I have also looked at turning my land packages to points and then joining back after the identity but given the placement of the point, it may not get the highest threshold for that package of land.

I need to do this with minimal manipulation as I need to be able to automate this process as there is lots of land packages with lots of flood scenarios I need to do this against.

I am using ArcGIS 10.2 for Desktop.

Comment: Are you doing this in ArcGis? if so please include tag. It sounds like you're barking up the right tree but what you're missing is getting the maximum and joining it back to the original polygons.. doing that is software dependent, after you've indicated which software package you're using to do this we can progress.

Comment: I think it is best to always say what you are using in the body of your question first. That way if you forget to tag or apply a less useful tag it can be easily corrected by many of us.

Comment: sorry Michael Miles-Stimson, I am using ArcGIS 10.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to do a [Spatial Join](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000000q000000). You'll use a one-to-one join_operation with the intersects match_option. In the field mappings you'll set it up so that if there are multiple matches found it will take the MAX value. Note that you may need to first create a numeric field in your flood polygons and convert any string based range values to integers (ie 2-5 won't work well, so just convert it to 5). Be careful with that, as if you do it on the ranges then 2-5 would return greater than 10 based on alpha sorting. Once the attribute is transferred over to your land packages, you can do the reverse to translate the numeric back to a string with the range if you need to, or just build it into your label expression.